# Google Apps Super Admin access to domain user calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a large number of resource calendars that my users need to have different degrees of access to depending on their roles.  I am writing an application to manage those Acl rules, but would like to also manage which calendars appear in end users calendar feeds (i.e. I don't want to have them suddenly see all 130 resource calendars and have to filter through them)

I need to use the CalendarList api access, but when I pass users//calendarList instead of users/me/calendarList authorized with Super Admin credentials, the service returns a 404 response.

My goal is to iterate through my list of shared calendar resources and for-each user who is a reader or freeBusyReader, set their calendarListEntry.hidden to true.

Comment: You have to show the code and exact error messages so we can help.

Comment: Ok, that is great. You can add your answer here so someone else having the same issue would benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered the answer.  In order to impersonate a user, you must set the "User" to the email address you wish to impersonate when initializing the service account credential:

`public static ServiceAccountCredential Credential(string[] Scopes, string impersonateEmail = null)
        {
            ServiceAccountCredential cred = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(credential_stream);
            var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cred.Id)
            {
                User = string.IsNullOrEmpty(impersonateEmail)?service_acct:impersonateEmail,
                Key = cred.Key,
                Scopes = Scopes
            };
            return new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);
        }`